# How to import keyboard shortcuts into Illustrator CC?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud, shortcuts

How to import custom keyboard shortcuts in Illustrator CC? Does it work with `Edit > My Parameter > Import` or is there something else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't a direct import option, but if you have a set of shortcuts saved on `Machine A`, then there will be a file `[set name].kys` in your prefs folder. You can copy this file to the prefs folder on `Machine B`, and then just go to `Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts` and choose your shortcut set.

For a full reference of where your preferences folder is, you can check [this adobe page](http://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/kb/preference-file-location-illustrator.html), but a general guide for CC is as follows (other versions very similar):

**Windows:** `Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator 18 Settings\en_US\x64\`

**Mac:** `/Users/<username>/Library/Preferences/Adobe Illustrator 17 Settings/en_US/`

Comment: This absolutely works in some cases. But users should be aware that often shortcuts are changed by Adobe. Moving old files to new versions can cause app crashes and other issues if Adobe has reworked the shortcuts. If you experience crashing or other issues, remove the shortcut file you moved and relaunch AI.

Comment: Worked my Illustrator CC 2019 to 2020 migration (macos). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I've had same issues with Photoshop cc2018 shortcuts.

Copying .kys files to AppData and Program Files folder didn't work(new sets didn't appear in Photoshop menu).

Just double-clicking .kys file made it work. It automatically opened program and asked if I want to import my shortcuts. Maybe the same simple trick will solve your problem too.